# Polynomials and roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The degree of all roots have to add up to the degree of the polynomial. Intuitively this makes sense, but could someone formally explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider multiplicities but it is true.

An easy proof by induction on the degree follows from this fact:

> $a$ is a root of $f$ iff $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ for some $g$.

In turn this fact follows from the polynomial division algorithm.

Comment: As mentioned by @doppz, you need to assume an algebraically closed field like $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're working over $\mathbf{C}$. Assume we have a polynomial $p = a_o + a_1x+ \dots +a_nx^n$, $a_i \in \mathbf{C}$, so that $\deg p =n$. Since $p$ is a complex polynomial we know it factors into a product of expressions of the form $(x-\xi_i)$ where $\xi_i$ is a root of $p$.

We know $(x-\xi_1)$ is a factor of $p$, so there is a polynomial $q_1$ such that $p=(x-\xi_1)q_1$. Moreover, we know $n=\deg p = \deg ( (x-\xi_1)q_1)=\deg(x-\xi_1)+\deg q_1.$ Now, $\deg (x-\xi_1)=1$ so that $\deg q_1= n-1$. Thus, by using induction, we can find $n$ roots of $p$, where obviously some roots can be repeated. At the $n$th step we will find a constant polynomial $q_n$ such that $q_{n-1}=(x-\xi_n)q_n$. Since $q_n$ is constant call it $C$. Thus we can back solve and find $p=C(x - \xi_1)\cdots(x-\xi_n)$. If we let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$ be the distinct roots of $p$ with multiplicities $e_1,\dots,e_m$, respectively. Then, $$p = C(x-\lambda_1)^{e_1}\cdots(x-\lambda_m)^{e_m}.$$
So that

$$n = \deg p = \deg (C(x-\lambda_1)^{e_1}\cdots(x-\lambda_m)^{e_m})=\\ \deg (x-\lambda_1)^{e_1} + \dots + \deg (x-\lambda_m)^{e_m} = e_1 + \dots + e_m.$$
Thus, the sum of the multiplicities of the distinct roots of $p$ equals the degree of $p$.